# Intel 9260 really slow under Ubuntu distros

Tags: drivers, wireless, internet, intel

The Intel 9260 Wifi+BT card is supposed to be well supported by linux right? Intel offers official drivers for it on their websites. The firmware files are in every major distro by default but how come it performs so badly for me? It has really, really slow speeds on Ubuntu /Ubuntu derivatives and manually copying over the firmware files from Intel's website doesn't do anything to fix it. Even installing the latest kernel on Ubuntu doesn't fix it. The only time the wifi card would work at full speeds was when I installed Fedora (stock ISO with gnome. the issue is still there when I used the KDE spin even when it was updated) and fully updated the kernel (it was really slow with the kernel that came with the ISO. It took forever for it to update the kernel). I even tried copying all the firmware files for the 9260 from a fully updated Fedora to an Ubuntu install and it wouldn't work. Any idea on what I should do? It is really holding me back from using Linux full time again.

Answer (score 0):

I would open terminal and do

```
sudo sed -i 's/wifi.powersave = 3/wifi.powersave = 2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf
systemctl restart network-manager.service
```

See if it is faster when network manager isn't able to activate wifi power management

Comment: 5.0 kernel fixed any issues so I guess Ubuntu 19.04+ will be plug and play for that wifi card now

Comment: Or you can use 18.04, enable proposed repos and install package linux-generic-hwe-18.04-edge and have the 5.0 kernel from 19.04